# What do I need to do to get the "2012 - it's almost there" achievement?

Tags: achievements, cargo-the-quest-for-gravity

In Cargo! The Quest For Gravity, there is a new achievement as part of the Christmas sale:

2012 - it’s almost there - The Christmas bell tolls! You have been blessed with a present.

I don't understand what this means.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [Steam thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=27072923):

> I started a new game and played a bit (to the point where you have to
>   attach a sail to your boat and collect sinking cargo) and it just
>   popped up. Matter of 5 minutes if you skip the cutscenes.
>
> That's what triggers it. Fix the sail and make your way towards the
>   sinking cargo. Then it just pops up out of nowhere. Easy achievement.

You do have to start a new game if you started the game before the achievement was added, though. The achievement is not integrated into old saves.